# Is there a portable way to query the type of void* pointer?

Tags: c, type-conversion, void-pointers

**Basic question**: is there a portable (or at least, a library that is found in most compilers) way to query the type of a void* pointer at runtime? In particular, is it possible to determine if the pointer is of type struct x or of type struct y (as an example).

**Additional info**: I know gcc offers the typeof operator, but I want a more portable, less compiler-dependent way of accomplishing the same thing.

**Requirements**:

1. Must not be completely compiler-dependent. This includes compiler-specific macros and other features not commonly implemented in most compilers.
2. I would prefer a function that works on any compiler over any less portable implementation (though I will accept the answer that best suits my goals).
3. It is okay to suggest using a function in a library that is not in the C11 function, but is commonly found in most compilers. Make sure you explain how it works and the arguments though.

Comment: `typeof` gives the static type (that is, the declared type); if you apply it to a `void *` expression, the type is `void *`, not what it originally was (if anything other than `void *`).

Comment: Hmmm… well, that would render that useless anyway; why would they include that if it cant tell you the one thing you need to know?

Comment: `#define SWAP(x, y) do { typeof(x) _tmp = (x); (x) = (y); (y) = _tmp; } while(0)`, for example. There is no run-time type information in C, if you need that information, you have to explicitly store it somewhere.

Comment: Something like `enum { IS_X, IS_Y }; struct X_or_Y { int which; union { struct X x; struct Y y; }; };` is a way to do that (before C11, the union must have a name). Alternatively, something akin to [this](http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex19.html) could be used (strictly speaking, the example in the link contains violations of strict aliasing, though).

Comment: @mafso The info in the link isnt what I'm looking for; the implementatioms share some similiarities, but are still very different. Also, I still have to supply an extra argument, so I think Im gonna keep it generic rather than a union. +1 for the union though, I'll remember that next time (so I don't have to make a second variable for casts)

Comment: There is no runtime typing... Types are eluded after compilation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're asking for is impossible. A `void *` pointer is *by definition* a generic pointer. It can be cast to or from a pointer of any type; there is no way to determine what type of data (if any!) it points to.

Comment: Would it be a problem if I try to access a field that doesnt exist or cast to the wrong type?

Comment: Then by definition, the only portable, non error-prone method to do this would be to have the function take another argument specifying the type of the void* pointer?

Comment: @Isaiah Depends on what you plan on doing with that pointer, but in general, yes.

Comment: @Isiah: If you need to cast a `void*` to something else, you need to know what type it actually points to.  If you designed your code such that there is only one possible type for that pointer, then you can just cast to that type.  However, if there is any ambiguity, then you'll need a second argument indicating the type.

Comment: As soon as I saw `impossible` +1.

Comment: I'm constructing items for a tex game I'm making; all special item abilities are done by calling a function which takes a void* parameter since a monster or a human might use it and I defined them differently.